# Save visitors detail information when visitor visit any page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

No matter which page the visitor has visited , I want to save the some information like ip address,country,location etc. into my database.

Is this a correct way of doing it in laravel ?

Comment: if you're happy with my answer below, accept it :)

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is [middleware](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-middleware-filter-style).

1. Create middleware:

```bash
artisan make:middleware StoreUserInfo
```

This command will create class `App\Http\Middleware\StoreUserInfo`

2. Edit StoreUserInfo class:

```php
<?php
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use DB;
use Session;

class StoreUserInfo
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!Session::get('user-info-stored')) {

            // write all what you need to DB

            // set session flag to prevent DB duplicates
            Session::put('user-info-stored', true);
        }
        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

---

Keep in mind that your software should be privacy-compliant. In some countries like Germany it's illegal to store user's IP address. Read more: https://github.com/piwik/piwik/issues/692